# Linq to entities navigation properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In entity framework i have two table (two entities): People and Role with one to many relationship.
In the People tables i have a navigation property to Role:

```
//People.cs
public virtual ICollection<Role> Role { get; set; }
```

Now i want retrieve all people that have role as 'barman'. How can i achieve this?
I want use linq to entities in the query expression method. I've tried:

```
var listPerson = (from p in SiContext.People
                 where p.Role.Name = 'barman'
                 select p).ToList();
```

The problem is that i cannot make p.Ruolo.Name because p.Ruolo is a ICollectionType that doesn't have the property "Name" (while the entity Role has that property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since role is a collection, you need to use `Any`

```
var listPerson = (from p in SiContext.People
                 where p.Role.Any(x => x.Name == "barman")
                 select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complemente your code include **ToLower()**:

```
var listPerson = (from p in SiContext.People
                 where p.Role.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "barman")
                 select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the order way around (assuming you have the reverse navigation property)

```
var listPerson = SiContext.Role.First(r => r.Name == "barman").People.ToList();
```