# Using Linq with navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Trying to use navigation properties in a Linq query and not getting any results. Not sure why.

I'm using the standard Simple Membership tables in SQL Server with Entity Framework. So I've pulled the three tables, AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles into my model (See pic below)

YES, I KNOW I CAN USE THE ROLE/IDENTITY FUNCTIONS, I AM JUST USING THESE TABLES TO TRY OUT THIS LINQ QUERY, THESE TABLES WERE CONVENIENT TO USE

Anyway, my goal was to use the Navigation properties to get the roles for a given user. AspNetUserRoles does not get pulled into my model as an entity since it has no primary key, so this seemed the right way to go. I tried using the suggestion presented here:

[Linq to entities navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615649/linq-to-entities-navigation-properties)

The following linq query returns 0 results

```
var result = (from r in context.AspNetRoles
         where r.AspNetUsers.Any(u => u.Id == UserId)
         select r).ToList();
return result;
```

Thought maybe I needed to use the Include extension so I tried this, also returns 0 results

```
var result = (from r in context.AspNetRoles
          where r.AspNetUsers.Any(u => u.Id == UserId)
          select r).Include("AspNetUsers").ToList();
return result;
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with the line:

```
where r.AspNetUsers.Any(u => u.Id == UserId)
```

because if I remove it, I get results but not for a specific user, of course.

I'm trying to follow the advice given in one of the answers here:

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Give some context, and preferably a sample model or two.

Comment: @stybl, edited the question. I hope that helps clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all of a User's roles based on their Id.

Unless there is some information I am missing about your User model, then it is impossible to get this without accessing `AspNetUserRoles`.

If you can access that table, then this becomes really straightforward:

```
var result = AspNetUserRoles.Where(role => role.UserId == UserId)
    .Select(userRole => AspNetRoles.First(role => role.Id == userRole.RoleId));
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var result = from userRole in AspNetUserRoles
             where userRole.UserId == UserId
             from role in AspNetRoles
             where role.Id == userRole.RoleId
             select role;
```

Comment: Problem with your query is that even though I include the AspNetUserRoles into the .edmx diagram, it doesn't get imported as a queryable entity because it has not primary key - therefore, it's presence serves to establish the navigation properties between AspNetUser and AspNetRoles. There is no AspNetUserRoles entity in the EF models even though I included it when I selected my tables. As I understand it, this is just how EF works. Thoughts?